# How to buy apps on Google Play while Google always reject my payments via Visa?

Tags: applications, google-play-store

Google always rejects my payments via Visa due to currency fluctuations and high bank fees. What should I do? Are there any alternatives or legal workarounds? FYI: Google Play cards is not available in my country.
[image: payment rejected]

Comment: Other options AFAIK are Paypal, and some prepaid cards (e.g. WireCard). Not sure if that would change things, though.

Comment: I don't have the option to pay via PayPal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try linking your credit card to you paypal as google play accepts paypal now.